# Determine the requested Controller in - ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in my ApplicationController I want to do something like this:

```
  def layout_by_resource
    if user_signed_in? || request.controller == 'ChatRoom'
      "application"
    else
      "unauthorized"
    end
   end
```

Is the **request.controller == 'ChatRoom'** part possible? I want to serve a specific layout based on the controller being called by the user.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, you could simply replace `request.controller == 'ChatRoom'` with `params[:controller] == 'ChatRoom'`

Alternative solution:

```
request.filtered_parameters["controller"] == 'ChatRoom'
```

Comment: Thanks but that gives me: 'undefined local variable or method `params' for ApplicationController:Class'

Comment: that's really weird your ApplicationController couldn't read your params

Comment: It sounds like you are calling `params` in the wrong place.  Also, you are going to get the underscore version of the controller name.  I posted code in an answer, but give apneadiving credit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this at the controller level.

```
def chatroom
  render(:layout => "layouts/application")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

ApplicationController:

```
layout :layout_by_resource

def layout_by_resource
    if user_signed_in? || params[:controller] == 'chat_room'
      "application"
    else
      "unauthorized"
    end
end
```