# Rails 3 - Dynamically change out css class based on Controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 application that is using the 960 grid CSS layout(s). There are a couple of different views that stretch in width and I am trying to come up with a good way to dynamically change out those classes.

For Example:
My Devise Controllers (`Sessions, Passwords, etc`) all use a certain class to restrict the width to `340px`, while most of my other controllers use another class to restrict the width to `540px`

So my `340px` layout uses class names `grid_6 push_5`, while my `540px` layout uses `grid_10 push_3`

Anyway to grab the accessed controller in the `application_controller`? My thinking is to just get the controller and have a switch statement that sets the class names in a `helper_method`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, thanks to this post: [Determine the requested Controller in - ApplicationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392401/determine-the-requested-controller-in-applicationcontroller)

Here is how I ended up doing it (application.html.erb):

```
<%= render :partial => 'common/content_container', :locals => { :controller => params[:controller] } %>
```

content_container partial:

```
<% case controller
    when "sessions", "passwords"
        container_div_grid_number = "6"
        container_div_push_number = "5"
    else
        container_div_grid_number = "10"
        container_div_push_number = "3"
    end 
%>

<div class="grid_<%= container_div_grid_number %> push_<%= container_div_push_number %> ">
    <div class="top_<%= container_div_grid_number %>"></div>
    <div class="middle_<%= container_div_grid_number %>">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_<%= container_div_grid_number %>"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: just for "good form", you might want to try moving that stuff to a helper so it isn't in the controller.  In the views, there is an attribute called `controller` that makes the current controller instance available to you so you can check which controller you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I actually need to modify my code above cause I changed the way I set the classes because I noticed that in the original markup some of the numbers (with in the main div) changed...